# No-op shell command that preserves $?

Tags: sh, posix, code-generation

Using only the features of the POSIX shell, is there a "simple command" that does nothing *and does not change the value of `$?`*  People usually describe `:` as a no-op command for shell, but this always sets `$?` to zero, so it's not what I want.

This is needed by a program that generates shell scripts.  In several places it needs to emit an if-then-else block

```
if CONDITION
then
    TRUE-COMMANDS
else
    FALSE-COMMANDS
fi
```

but, because of further complications that I'd rather not try to explain right now, it cannot reliably tell whether `TRUE-COMMANDS` and `FALSE-COMMANDS` are empty.  An empty then- or else-clause will be a shell syntax error.

`:` can be put at the beginning of the `then`-clause to take care of `TRUE-COMMANDS` being empty, but that won't work for `FALSE-COMMANDS` because it clobbers `$?` and the `FALSE-COMMANDS` might want to look at the value `$?` was set to by the condition.  For the same reason, `:` can't be put *after* `FALSE-COMMANDS`—the code after the if-then-else might want to see `$?` from the last operation within the if-then-else.

Bonus points if you can avoid:

- Forking: `(exit $?)` does the job, but there are so many of these conditional blocks in a generated script that it produces a measurable slowdown.
- Functions: given `nop () { return $? }` then `nop` does the job, but due to *more* complications that I'd rather not get into, it's not practical to have `nop` defined sufficiently early for all of the places that would need it.

Comment: I think that CONDITION will set $?; so you can't evaluate your `if` without setting it.

Comment: @mevets Yes, that's exactly the problem. `status=$?` at the beginning of the `FALSE-COMMANDS` needs to set `status` to the exit status of `CONDITION`, not to zero.  If I put a `:` immediately after `else` that won't happen.

Comment: otherwise you could put a `while CONDITION; do : ; done` as your null statement for the else clause, since CONDITION can't be true, it would never execute.

Comment: @mevets `CONDITION` may have side effects, so that's no good.

Comment: `function r() { return $1; }` then `x=$?; if CONDITION; then r $x; else ls; fi`

Comment: How do you not know if `FALSE-COMMANDS` is empty if you are the one *generating* it? This sounds like an XY problem; you should be asking how to tell if the command list is empty or not.

Comment: @chepner Read all of https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/autoconf.git/tree/lib/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4 and .../m4sh.m4, paying particular attention to the comments above AS_IF, m4_expand, and m4_provide, and then if you can think of something I'm all ears.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @chepner The question I asked is answerable as is. I'm not going to put any more effort into an alternate approach that I had already decided was not feasible before I asked the question.

Comment: There is no command that doesn't alter `$?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to make use of a simple assignment. Instead of using `:`, do `_rc=$?`.

```
if condition; then
   [ list-true ]     # optional 
   _rc=$?
else
   [ list-false ]    # optional
   _rc=$?
fi
( exit $_rc )        # optional
list-post-if
```

Using this variable `_rc`, you have stored the exit status of the last executed command, whether this is `condition` or the last command in `list-true` or `list-false`.

- The arguments in favour of this method is the low overhead of an assignment.
- The argument against is the need to at least rewrite `list-post-if` to make use of `_rc` instead of `$?`.
- If the latter is not possible, or too tedious, you might concider to add a `(exit $_rc)` just after the conditional statement. This, however, requires a sub-shell, but it is only one.

Comment: After some thought, I gave user3840170 the bounty because I appreciate their digging through POSIX to confirm that I hadn't missed any possibilities, but I'm accepting *this* answer which gave me a new possibility anyway.

Comment: @zwol Thanks, very much appreciated and good decision to give user3840170 the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

It’s certainly not possible in a POSIX-compliant shell to write a command that does not touch `$?`. By reading through IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 vol. 3 chapter 2 ‘Shell Command Language’, we learn that:

- §2.8.2 says that ‘[e]ach command has an exit status’ (so no command has no exit status).
- §2.5.2 ‘Special Parameters’ says that `$?` ‘[e]xpands to the decimal exit status of the most recent pipeline (see Section 2.9.2)’.
- §2.9.2 ‘Pipelines’ says that a pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands, optionally preceded (as a whole) by `!`, with commands joined by `|`. About exit status, it says

  > If the pipeline does not begin with the `!` reserved word, the exit status shall be the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline. Otherwise, the exit status shall be the logical NOT of the exit status of the last command.
- §2.9 ‘Shell Commands’ defines a ‘command’ and says that ‘[u]nless otherwise stated, the exit status of a command shall be that of the last simple command executed by the command’. A ‘command’ may be any of the following:

  - A simple command (§2.9.1), which is simply an external program, a shell built-in or a variable assignment (without a command name). The former will of course return the exit status of the command executed. About the latter, the specification says:

    > If there is no command name, but the command contained a command substitution, the command shall complete with the exit status of the last command substitution performed. Otherwise, the command shall complete with a zero exit status.
  - A pipeline, described by §2.9.2 mentioned above.
  - A compound-list (§2.9.3), which is a sequence of one or more {sequences of one or more {sequences of one or more pipelines (see above), joined by `&&` or `||`}, each terminated by `;` or `&` (with a final `;` optional)}, joined by newline characters. A compound-list returns the exit status of the last pipeline executed synchronously; asynchronously-executed pipelines (those terminated by `&`) set exit status to zero. None of the sequences may be empty, which guarantees at least one pipeline will be executed.
  - A compound command (§2.9.4), which is either:

    - A subshell or a braced compound-list (§2.9.4.1), which returns the exit status of the underlying compound-list (see above).
    - A conditional construct (`case`, §2.9.4.3 or `if`, §2.9.4.4) or a loop (`for`, §2.9.4.2; `while`, §2.9.4.5; `until`, §2.9.4.6). If the body of this construct is not executed, it returns an exit status of zero.
  - A function definition (§2.9.5), which returns an exit status of zero if the definition is accepted, and a non-zero status otherwise.
- And finally, §2.9.4.4 ‘The if Conditional Construct’ defines the condition and the body of the `if` construct to be a compound-list, described by §2.9.3 mentioned above. This means that the body of an `if` construct will always contain at least one command that will clobber `$?`. The specification does not even leave any wiggle room for ‘implementation-defined behaviour’.

All of the above means that the only way to write a no-op command that preserves `$?` is by reading out the value in `$?` and returning it back. There are three constructs in POSIX shell that are capable of this, two of which are already mentioned in the question body: an `exit` from a subshell or a function invocation.

The third is `.`: the shell sourcing statement mentioned in @Jens’ answer. By sourcing a script containing just a `return "$?"` command, the value of `$?` can be preserved. However, this requires you to arrange that a suitable script is found at some known location, which I assume to be just as inconvenient as ensuring that a no-op function has been defined early enough in the file (if not in fact more).

If you bend the strict POSIX requirement a little, even this can be overcome, though:

```
. /dev/stdin <<EOF
return "$?"
EOF
```

`/dev/stdin` is not a POSIX feature, but is widely available; it is explicitly listed in IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 vol. 1 §2.1.1 as an extension. The above snippet has been tested to work in bash 5.0.8, dash 0.5.11 and busybox sh 1.30.1 on Linux (with appropriately set-up `/dev` and so on).

Comment: After some thought, I'm giving you the bounty because I appreciate your digging through POSIX to confirm that I hadn't missed any possibilities, but I'm accepting kvantour's answer which gave me a new possibility anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let anyone tell you there are only functions and sub-shells.

Can you create or distribute another tiny file? If so, you can create a file with just

```
return $?
```

and then source it as an "empty" command keeping the exit status:

```
$ echo 'return $?' > keepstatus
$ ls foobar
ls: fooobar: No such file or directory
$ . ./keepstatus
$ echo $?
2
$ sleep 100
^C
$ . ./keepstatus
$ echo $?
130
```

Doesn't fork, doesn't use functions, no extra variable, keeps the status and is as POSIXly as they come.

There's even a fourth way I can see, when I sacrifice the bonus points for forking and assuming, since you are in autoconf m4 territory, that finding and using a host compiler is a breeze.

```
cat > keepstatus.c <<EOF
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return argv[1] ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
}
EOF
$CC -o keepstatus keepstatus.c
```

Then use `/path/to/keepstatus $?`.

Comment: I think this works nicely, but would reading an external file not create more overhead then calling a subshell? I've attempted something similar using a heredoc, but that does not work at all. Nonetheless, upvote.

Comment: @kvantour I'd say it's less overhead, since subshells need to do some bookkeeping, while sourcing is open/read/execute/close. But I've never implemented a shell so this might all be fantasy :-)

Comment: Arranging for a separate file to exist in a known location is probably even more trouble than ensuring that a function is defined early enough in the same script, which the asker mentioned as not being particularly feasible. So that’s not really a solution.

Comment: @user3840170 How do you know that? The user is creating shell code. A single `return $?` is exactly a tiny bit of that. Oh, and I am still waiting for an answer why you stole my solution and plagiarized it into your answer. What has become of credit where credit is due?

Comment: I don’t – but the asker wanted a solution in POSIX shell, so the worst-case assumption is that it should be able to run as-is on an arbitrary POSIX system, where such things have *not* been pre-arranged, especially since it was mentioned that defining a no-op function early enough would not be particularly convenient. So I assume pre-arranging other things would be just as inconvenient.

Comment: The easiest way for the generated script to ensure that such a `return $?` one-liner is available would be to create it in `/tmp` early within the generated script itself – but then, you might as well put a definition of a no-op function there and dispense with the one-liner script altogether.

Comment: Also, you got your credit, what more do you want? I also did add the `/dev/stdin` bit, so it’s not like I added *nothing* to it.

Comment: @user3840170 I find your attitude to second guess what is a solution pretty rude. This is entirely for zwol to decide. My solution fits all of his requirements and violates none of his no-gos. I even had to correct you on the POSIXness of `.` (dot).

Comment: It would be *slightly* easier for me to prearrange the existence of this helper script than to prearrange a shell function. However, I would also have to arrange for the helper to be cleaned up afterward, and trap 0 is already being used for something unrelated, so on the whole this approach isn't any easier than using a function.